# Update array element value in typescript ( Angular )

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 5. I need to update the array value based selectedMobile.
My coding :

```
const mobilelist = [
    { 'key': 'apple', 'name': 'Apple', 'checked': false },
    { 'key': 'sumsung', 'name': 'Sumsung', 'checked': false },
    { 'key': 'oneplus', 'name': 'Oneplus', 'checked': false },
    { 'key': 'mi', 'name': 'Mi', 'checked': false }
  ]; 
const selectedMobile = ['apple']; 
const newmobilelist: any = [];
if (selectedMobile.length > 0) {
  mobilelist.forEach(element => {
    if (selectedMobile.find(x => x == element.key) != null) {
      newmobilelist.push({ 'key': element.key, 'name': element.name, 'checked': true });
    } else {
      newmobilelist.push({ 'key': element.key, 'name': element.name, 'checked': false });
    }
  });
}
console.log(newmobilelist);
```

In console, I am expecting result like :

```
[
  { 'key': 'apple', 'name': 'Apple', 'checked': true },
  { 'key': 'sumsung', 'name': 'Sumsung', 'checked': false },
  { 'key': 'oneplus', 'name': 'Oneplus', 'checked': false },
  { 'key': 'mi', 'name': 'Mi', 'checked': false }
];
```

But above code return like :

```
[
  { 'key': 'apple', 'name': 'Apple', 'checked': false },
  { 'key': 'sumsung', 'name': 'Sumsung', 'checked': false },
  { 'key': 'oneplus', 'name': 'Oneplus', 'checked': false },
  { 'key': 'mi', 'name': 'Mi', 'checked': false }
];
```

I don't why?, Please help to resolve...

Comment: This works as expected on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6nz7qx0/1/ and should work with Angular as well. Is this all you are doing or is there more code?

Comment: your code works fine for me in my javascript console (if I remove the ':any' to make it pure JavaScript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already said, your code seems to be working fine. However, it's unnecessarily complicated, you can drastically shrink it like this.

```js
const mobilelist = [
    { 'key': 'apple', 'name': 'Apple', 'checked': false },
    { 'key': 'sumsung', 'name': 'Sumsung', 'checked': false },
    { 'key': 'oneplus', 'name': 'Oneplus', 'checked': false },
    { 'key': 'mi', 'name': 'Mi', 'checked': false }
];
const selectedMobile = ['apple'];
const newmobilelist = mobilelist.map(x => { x.checked = selectedMobile.includes(x.key); return x});
console.log(newmobilelist)
```